# get different between date in DOM

Tags: date, vue.js

I'm trying to calculate different between 2 date, 
if date1 - date2 >= 6 hours it will show the image
but its not working

```
  <img
     v-else-if="dateList[0] > day.date >= 6"
     class="imagePosition"
     :src="fillCheckImage"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `dateList[0]` and `day.date` are JS `Date` objects you can use `getTime` to get the time in milliseconds and then compute the difference.

```
<img v-if="(dateList[0].getTime() - day.date.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 ) >= 6" ... />
```

or even simpler you can just subtract them

```
<img v-if="(dateList[0] - day.date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 ) >= 6" ... />
```